# $\lim _{n\to\infty} (\min \{x_n,y_n\})=\min \{\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n, \lim_{n\to\infty} y_n \}.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> $x_n$ and $y_n$ are bounded number sequences. Prove that
> $$\lim _{n\to\infty} \bigl(\min \{x_n,y_n\}\bigr)=\min \left\{\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n,  \lim_{n\to\infty} y_n \right\}.$$

Does that also mean that:

$$\lim _{n\to\infty} \bigl(\max \{x_n,y_n\}\bigr)=\max \left\{\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n,  \lim_{n\to\infty} y_n \right\}?$$

Comment: what have you tried ? where are you stuck ?

Comment: @Surb I think i shoud use limit inferior monotonicity to prove the $>=$ part  put im not sure how to do it

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Note that for any $a, b\in \mathbb R$, 
$2\min \{a, b\} =a+b-|a-b|$ 
Similarly, modify the above for $\max \{a, b\} $